# How to display records by matching the text in a textbox?

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview, textbox, record

I have two tables which is appointment table and medical centre which have relationship with each other using mcID. Right now my appointment form, i use outer join to display the mcCentre in medicalcentre table instead of mcID in the gridview. U see in my form, all medical centre(mcCentre) is displayed in the gridview. But I only want Hwang and Liang Family Clinic record to display as I want to match the text in the textbox which is Hwang and Liang Family Clinic. That means watever hospital text is in the textbox, I ony want that hospital record to appear in the gridview. the textbox name is txtCentre.

[image]

[image]

```
 private void LoadAppointmentRecords()
{

    //retrieve connection information info from App.config
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SACPConnection"].ConnectionString;
    //STEP 1: Create connection
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    //STEP 2: Create command
    //string strCommandText = "SELECT appointmentID, convert(varchar, aDate, 103) AS aDate, aTime, aStatus, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, patientID, mcID, nurseID FROM APPOINTMENT";

    string strCommandText = "SELECT appointmentID, convert(varchar, aDate, 103) AS aDate, aTime, aStatus, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, pat.pFirstName, pat.pLastName, cen.mcCentre, nur.nUsername FROM APPOINTMENT AS app";
    strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN PATIENT as pat on app.patientid = pat.patientid";
    strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN MEDICALCENTRE as cen on app.mcid = cen.mcid";
    strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN NURSE as nur on app.nurseid = nur.nurseid";
    //strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN NURSE as nur on app.nurseid = nur.nurseid";

    AppointmentAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommandText, myConnect);

    //command builder generates Select, update, delete and insert SQL
    // statements for MedicalCentreAdapter
    //SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(AppointmentAdapter);
    // Empty Employee Table first
    Appointment.Clear();
    // Fill Employee Table with data retrieved by data adapter
    // using SELECT statement
    AppointmentAdapter.Fill(Appointment);

    // if there are records, bind to Grid view & display
    if (Appointment.Rows.Count > 0)
        grdApp.DataSource = Appointment;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your string... This will match whatever is in your txtCentre.Text even when the text is not completely typed yet, just matching a few characters or words would do.

```
 strCommandText += " WHERE mcCentre like '%" + txtCentre.Text.Replace("'", "''").Trim() + "%'";
```

This will match whatever is in txtCentre.Text exactly...

```
strCommandText += " WHERE mcCentre like '" + txtCentre.Text.Replace("'", "''").Trim() + "'";
```

Adding .Replace("'", "''").Trim() to your Text should help you avoid SQL injection without using parameters, but if you want to use parameters, you can follow Jon Barker's method :)

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind you're exposing yourself to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks with this method. I'd recommend using an ORM such as entity framework. If you still want to work with direct SQL as chris_techno25 posted, then always use parameters, as opposed to directly embedding the string from the user, unsanitised.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter